# How delete all children except 1 specific widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Frame in which I am trying to delete all child widgets except one in particular. I am familiar with deleting ALL children with:

```
for child in frame.winfo_children():
    child.destroy()
```

I can even prevent the deletion of a particular TYPE of widget (say, a Button) via:

```
for child in frame.winfo_children():
    if child.winfo_class() != 'Button':
        child.destroy()
```

What I want is to be able to delete all children, of all types, except for 1 specific widget. Here is a fully-functional example below. I want to destroy everything EXCEPT `keep_me`.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
keep_me = tk.Button(frame, text='Keep me')
keep_me.grid(column=0, row=0)
destroy_me = tk.Button(frame, text='Expendable')
destroy_me.grid(column=0, row=1)

for child in frame.winfo_children():
    # Here's where I need help. Don't know how to single-out 'keep_me'
    child.destroy()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just see if the variable you've used to save the widget is equal to the child, ie.

```
for child in frame.winfo_children():
    # Here's where I need help. Don't know how to single-out 'keep_me'
    if child != keep_me:
        child.destroy()
```

Comment: ... if you'll excuse me, I'm just going to go punch myself in the face

Comment: Glad I could help